# GIT - Porque me aparece origin/main si antes solo me salia HEAD -> main?

Tags: git, github, originmain

Soy principiante en GIT, quizé actualizar mi proyecto en python y hoy me aparecio ese cambio. Quisiera saber porque me aparece eso...[![][1]][1]
Además, me ha generado algunas complicaciones al volver al primer commit puesto que lo queria renombrar...

```
PS C:\Users\walinn\Documentos\practicas\PY-LVL\registro_de_alumnos> git lg
* 1b20575 - (29 minutes ago) 1.3 Registro de notas y alumnos - Colorama y Two Spaces - Walin Paredes (HEAD -> main, origin/main)
* 692fe54 - (13 days ago) 1.2 Version | Registro de notas y alumnos - Clear .txt - Walin Paredes
* c7abc52 - (13 days ago) 1.1 Version | Registro de notas y alumnos - encoding='utf-8' - Walin Paredes
* d64ccd9 - (2 weeks ago) 1.0 Version | Resgitro de notas y Alumnos - Walin Paredes
PS C:\Users\walinn\Documentos\practicas\PY-LVL\registro_de_alumnos> git branch
* main
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Podrías reemplazar la foto y colocar el texto (de la consola) directamente en la pregunta?

Comment: el codigo va en formato texto, justamente porque tu imagen no se distinte bien y no se puede copiar el codigo. [edit] tu pregunta y agrega el codigo como corresponde.

Comment: Esto te ayudará a entender https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/git-los-conceptos-de-master-origin-y-head.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No hay nada raro en ello. `HEAD -> main` indica que estás trabajando sobre la rama (*local*) `main`. Pero un commit puede estar siendo apuntado por varias referencias (ramas, etiquetas) y en este caso la rama `main` en el remoto `origin` está apuntando a ese mismo commit en el que estás actualmente. Si antes no lo viste podria ser porque:

- no habías empujado la rama aún
- hiciste un pull/merge
- retrocediste en la historia (otra rama podría estar más alante o hiciste un reset)

Seguramente hay otras explicaciones sencillas.